# delete all files in a directory with multiple extensions

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have files that fall into two extension categories (.out and .error). Is there a single command that can delete them all at once?

I tried `rm -f *.out || *.error` but it did not work. Thanks

(i saw the linked post too but am not sure how to deal with multiple extensions still)

Edit: non recursive case

Comment: `shopt -s globstar; rm **/*.{out,error}`, or `find . -type f \( -iname '*.out' -o -iname '*.error' \) -delete`

Comment: your command removes all .out files, and only if that [||] failed (none-found or permissions errors) process the names of all files ending in .error as commands - yuk!   your description doesn't match what your command.   a `rm *.out *.error` would have done what you want (-f if you need it, assuming current directory only)

Comment: The answer is simple: `rm *.out *error`. Note that muru's commands above are recursive -- i.e. they will delete files in subdirectories too.

Comment: @muru See OP's edit. The question is not quite the same. OP is asking about multiple extensions, non-recursive deletion. The linked question is about one extension, recursive deletion.

Comment: @wjandrea are you sure it's non-recursive?

Comment: @muru yeah, op didn't mention anything about recursion.

Comment: @wjandrea but they did say *all* files.

Comment: Thanks wjandrea and @muru. I don't know why that didn't come to me (considering this is default in a lot of canonical programs like mkdir [dir1, ...] and cat [file1,..])

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `||` is not needed there<sup>1</sup>, `rm` will act on all operands, so:

```
rm *.error *.out
```

Or, using bash's brace expansion (useful if you have a long list):

```
rm *.{error,out}
```

<sup>1</sup>Not only is `||` is not needed, it also changes the command structure. `||` is bash's OR for *commands*. So, if you had files `a.error`, `b.error`, and `a.out`, `b,out`, bash would execute:

```
rm a.out b.out
```

And if *that* fails, then execute `a.error` with `b.error` as an argument. It won't be passing `a.error` or `b.error` to a second run of `rm`.